# Fail to drag and drop element (disappears when drag is released)

Tags: android, user-interface, drag-and-drop, listener

I have 2 EditText's that I want to be able to drag and drop onto my screen. The problem that I'm having right now is that they drag fine - but when the drag is released, rather than being dropped the EditText disappears.

I'm setting the listeners like such:

```
//etUsername and etPartnerName are the EditText's I want to make draggable
etUsername.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
etUsername.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
etPartnerName.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());    
etPartnerName.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
```

On the same Fragment, I have the classes of the listeners:

```
    private final class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);

            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
    class MyDragListener implements View.OnDragListener {
    View draggedView;
    EditText dropped;
    private android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();

                // Do nothing
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                int x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                int y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord;
                layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord;
                v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                // Do nothing
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

                // Do nothing
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Can't find a working solution online and have tried following a few tutorials and end up with the same result. Can anyone see where the mistake is?

Highly appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You did the same mistake as so many developers do in misunderstand the concept of android [Drag And Drop](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html) concept.

When you set the On View.OnDragListener listener that mean that the view that register to the listener will get the events of the Drag event. So basically if the only events that you register is the EditTexts themselves, all the logic you putted in the ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED, ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION, ACTION_DRAG_EXITED, ACTION_DRAG_DROPPED is useless for most the time.

I'm guess to that you think that the logic you put in the events is what make the View to follow your finger. Well if you think so it really wrong because the Framework itself manage the View you see dragginh on your screen.

To summarize things, the View is disappear because you called:

```
 view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

in the beginning and never changed it back. So to see your View again you need to insert into your MyDragListener :

```
 case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
```

This mean that never mind what happened in the logic if the listener, the View will be visible at the end.

For your other goal, to drop the View in the right position, you need to register DragListener to the parent of the Views that will get the location of the dragging process in the DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION, save the position of the event, and assign this values in DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED of the EditText that finish to drag.

Comment: Thanks, I made the change to DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED - didn't seem to fix the problem. Are you suggesting that I write the listener classes in the host activity? Right now this is done in a Fragment that covers just the bottom half of an activity, but I want to be able to drag the EditText's from the fragment onto the activity itself (top half).

Comment: first try to isolate the problem by remove all the code in the listener except from the DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED. and for any other case return true. In this way in the end of the drag you should see your invisible EditText again

Comment: I have just tried this but I get the same result for some reason. The EditText's just disappear the second I release my tap - anything else I can try?

Comment: You removed all other code in the DragListener except ACTION_DRAG_ENDED?

Comment: Yep, same result so maybe the problem is somewhere else?  I noticed that when the visibility is changed  to VISIBLE (in the touch listener), it still disappears, but the original EditText remains in its position. However, a lot of strange behaviour happens when I do this, like the fragment layout eventually increasing in height, and parts of the ORIGINAL EditText disappearing

Comment: Try to: 1. move the setVisibility before the startDrag(). 2. return true always in the OnTouchListener. In addition put log in  DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED, DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED: to see  if they called

Comment: Moving setVisibility before startDrag() didn't work. It seems DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED and DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED are never called (checked using the debugger too).

Comment: OK so now put the DragListener not on the EditText but on the root view for them and change to : case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED: {
                    ((View)event.getLocalState()).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

Comment: This mean that you will received the events in the host view and you pull the View that trigger the drag inside getLocalState(), because you putted it there when you built your DragShadowView

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87297/discussion-between-eyes-enberg-and-yshahak).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, You are not making your EditText visible after Drag is exited.
So, Replace is your below code from :

```
case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            x_cord = (int) event.getX();
            y_cord = (int) event.getY();
            layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord;
            layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord;
            v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            break;
```

To the below code:

```
case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                Log.e(TAG, "Drag Exited");
                x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                view.setX(x_cord - (view.getWidth() / 2));
                view.setY(y_cord - (view.getWidth() / 2));
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make the dragged view visible again after dragging like this

```
@Override
public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent event) 
{

    View dragView = (View) event.getLocalState();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            dragView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

**edit**

Added code to prevent `ConcurrentModificationException`

```
@Override
public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent event) 
{

    final View dragView = (View) event.getLocalState();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            view.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    dragView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```